# Server-side validating HTML form input with a long series of if / else statements - efficient?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

Is it efficient to simply use a long series of nested if / else statements in PHP to validate user input from an HTML form?

So say there's two fields, I'm just approaching it like this:

```
if ( field one is formatted right ) {
   if ( field one is long enough ) {
           if ( field two is ok ) {
               do stuff;
           }
           else {
               echo "field two is not ok!";
           }
   }
    else {
        echo "field one is not long enough!";
    }
}
else {
 echo "field one is not formatted right!";
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

So when there are several fields and a lot of validation to do, and different kinds of validation for each field, this ends up being quite long.

Is this a bad way to deal with this?

Comment: Why don't you just put a series of if statements that are not nested? For example put a flag variable at the top and set it to true. Then if any of the fields do not meet your requirements set the flag to false. After all the fields have been evaluated you will know if any of them were false and if you make a flag for each field which ones were false.

Comment: I think this depends on the scale of what you're doing. You could implement some sort of validation class

Comment: Does it make it less efficient to nest them? I assumed it was better to nest them, because then if the input fails the first test we don't bother checking everything else.

Comment: It would technically be quicker but perhaps not for the user. See my above comment. If they enter data wrong on 3 fields your approach will only alert them that they have one field wrong when in reality they have 3.

Comment: If you're talking about a form you don't want to stop checking the validations as you may have multiple errors to highlight to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i usually do is something like:

```
$error_msg = '';
if (field1 not valid)
    $error_msg .= 'Field One is not valid.<br>';

if (field2 not valid)
    $error_msg .= 'Field two is not valid.<br>';

if ($error_msg == '')
{
    // DO ALL YOUR VALID SUBMISSION STUFF HERE
}
```

I usually think its better to notify the user of all their errors at once instead of one at a time to annoy them.

Comment: And there's no efficiency issue even if there are a lot of checks to make?

Comment: whats a lot?  I doubt it would make any difference.  Also it would be better to display all the errors the first time instead of one at a time to save hits on the server and annoying the user.

Comment: @葛修远 Even if it's not efficient, I can't think of any better way.

Comment: +1 since this will show all of the errors at once, unlike my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work, and one way to determine its efficiency would be to use profiling to actually measure how long it takes.

An alternative way to validate would be something like this:

```
function handle_submission(){
   $field_1_validation_result=validate_field_1_value($field_1_value);
   if($field_1_validation_result!==true)exit($field_1_validation_result);

   $field_2_validation_result=field_2_validation_result($field_2_value);
   if($field_2_validation_result!==true)exit($field_2_validation_result);

   //Everything is right
   do stuff
}

function validate_field_1_value($value){
   if ( !field one is formatted right )return "field one is not formatted right";
   if ( !field one is long enough )return "field one is not long enough";
   return true;
}



function validate_field_2_value($value){
   if( !field two is ok)return "field two is not ok"
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thinking forward there are definitely better ways you can approach this. For a start you can instead try to create something like a validation class with pre-defined validation methods.

Take for (a very rough) example:

```
class Validator {

    public function validate($args) {
        $errors = array();
        //Make sure to do any santising you need too
        foreach($args as $field=>$data) {
            if ($response = $field($data))
                $errors[$field] = $response; 

            //You could create break code here if you wanted 
            //to check if the form was invalid without detailed feedback
        }
        if (empty($errors)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $errors;
    }

    private function email_field($data) {
        $valid = true;

        //perform a validation on email here, generate an $err_msg if it's not valid

        if ($valid) 
            return false;

        return $err_msg
    }
}

$validator = new Validator();

//You probably want to explode or loop through the error messages
//Or for extra brownie points, use the key of each element in the array to place
//the error message intelligently within your HTML!
$validation_errs = $validator->validate($_POST);
if ($validation_errs) 
    print_r($validation_errs);
```

Combined with your form...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="email_field" />
</form>
```

This could then be combined to provide your validation. The reason this may be better is that you could use this class throughout your site, meaning you don't have to duplicate your validation logic, and more importantly you don't have to have trails of nested logic for each form. You simply pass the post variables, your class will automatically run the validation that it requires, and give you back either an all clear (unintuitively, "false" here, sorry) or an array of validation error messages paired with the field name they came from.

**Furthermore** this then becomes useful when dealing with combining serverside and clientside validation, allowing you to use AJAX to call very specific, single field, validation queries to your PHP over AJAX and returning you the response that can be used (as long as you are doing enough with your output to ensure it is valid for AJAX communication).

So, when it comes to efficiency, it's not just about what is important now, or how negligible the performance differences might be...it's about how much time it will save you later, when your form changes, when your validation logic has to be altered, and when you need to reuse the same validation logic over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that formatting like this is easier to read and follow:

```
if ( field one is not formatted right ) {
    echo "field one is not formatted right!"

} else if ( field one is no long enough ) {
    echo "field one is not long enough!";

} else if ( field two is not ok) {
    echo "field two is not ok!";

} else  {
    do stuff;
}
```

Comment: this would only produce one error at a time which would mean the user would have to submit the form many times to view all their errors

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do most of the times:

```
$Errors = array();

if (field one is not formatted right)
    $Errors[] = "Field one is not formatted right.";

if (field one is not long enough)
    $Errors[] = "Field one is not long enough.";

if (field two is not ok)
    $Errors[] = "Field two is not ok.";

if (empty($Errors)) {
    do stuff;
} else {
    foreach ($Errors as $Error) {
        echo '<div class="error">' . $Error . '</div>';
    }
}
```

This is similar to other answers only that I use an array to store the error messages so that I can format them easier.